# Setting a datasource for a report at runtime?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a form on my screen with a reportviewer control.  I want to create a report, but since my dataset/datatable is defined within my program and not with a wizard, my dataset doesn't appear as a choice when trying to define a new report on the reportviewer.

So, my question is, "How can I use my 'internally described' dataset as the datasource for the .rdlc/reportviewer control?"

Thanks for any advice and help.

Also, before anyone asks, the dataset is filled with data from within the program, so it is not databound to any outside datasource.  I basically have a dataset with data in it and I want it to appear on the reportviewer.

Thanks, again!

Comment: I think I may have just found my answer: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/magreer/archive/2008/10/16/setting-the-datasource-for-a-report-at-runtime.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was exactly what I was looking for here:

[Setting the datasource for a Report at runtime](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/magreer/archive/2008/10/16/setting-the-datasource-for-a-report-at-runtime.aspx)

Hopefully, this will help someone else.